# show the whole text in one textbox and the words in another box

Tags: c#, loops, text

help please 
i want the program to take the text from text box 1 
display all the text in text box 2 
and if it meets a space stop and  display the word in text box 3 
the program display the entire text in text box 2 but it does not work for text box 3
help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[] sent = new string[100];
        string[] word = new string[50];


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
            {
                sent[i] = textBox1.Text;  
                textBox2.Text = sent[i];
                for (int j = 0; j <= textBox1.Text.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (sent[i] == " ")
                        word[j] = sent[i];
                    textBox3.Text = word[j];
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given a text: `This is a sentence.` in your TextBox1, what exact output you want in TextBox2 and TextBox3?

Comment: Let's start by putting sentences in the *question*. Sentences start with capital letters and end with punctuation marks (like periods).

Comment: And without exactly understanding your problem, i can say that you don't need those loops (and definitely not the second loop).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split up the text, use the `String.Split` to give you an array of words:

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what is outlined in the "question" and assumes a singular "word" may be among the input. Such as "dfsgkujhdafkj;hsadfkjsd word sdfkjhsdfkjsdf"

```
        string originalText = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    textBox2.Text = originalText;
    textBox3.Text = originalText.Contains(" ") ? originalText.Substring(originalText.IndexOf(" "), (originalText.Substring(originalText.IndexOf(" ") + 1).Contains(" ") ? originalText.Substring(originalText.IndexOf(" ") + 1).IndexOf(" ") + 1 : originalText.Length - originalText.IndexOf(" "))) : string.Empty;
```